# Normal Approximation to the Binomial

Tags: probability

I need to solve this problem using Normal Approximation to the Binomial Distribution to check if the value is similar to the one that I found using the Binomial distribution.

Question:

What is the probability that in a group of $100$ people, $10$ of them were born in either March and April.

I alredy know that using binomial distribution the result will be: $0.02093$

Now in the case of:

Binomial distribution: $X \sim B(n,p)$

Where I know that $n=100$ and probability of success $p$ is $\frac{61}{365}$.

So, $X \sim B(100,\frac{61}{365})$

Mean $=16.7123$

Variance $=13.9193$

But because it is continuous, we cannot calculate the prob. of one exact value, we need to find $P(X=10)$ using the area under the normal curve.
So $9.5<10<10.5$. Then I did:

$P(Z<\frac{10.5-16.7123}{\sqrt{13.9193}})$-$P(Z<\frac{9.5-16.7123}{\sqrt{13.9193}})$ =

$0.9525-0.9732$ (using the table book) which is equal to :

$-0.0207$ which is a negative value close to the value that I need but is negative.

I do not know what am I doing wrong can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: It looks good so far, what did you do after P(Z.....?

Comment: I did a mistake, now the question is completed

Comment: For the value of 10.5 I find a z=-1.67 and for the 9.5 I find z=-1.93 The values from the Standard normal table are 0.0475 and 0.0268 respectively. When subtracting, I get a positive. How did you look up the z-values?

Comment: well maybe this is my problem I probably looked to the wrong table, So if I use these values that you told, it will give 0.0207 which is close to 0.0293 so it should be correct right?

Comment: Well, what's close? I think it deviates considerably, but then, the $n$ is only 100, so the normal approximation isn't that good. But as an exercise it is ok of course.

Comment: It has over two years. Would you consider deleting this question post? I assume you have already got your answer here or elsewhere and moved on.

Comment: Hello? Are you there? Again, please post an answer and accept it yourself (self-answering is encouraged on the site), or deleting this question post to wrap it up.  otherwise it's clogging the system.